# Create a Database while installing

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a project which uses data from a database. Now I wanted to package it and have made a setup.py for it using help from [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html). Now when I run setup.py from terminal it installs the package. The database is created using a create_db.py script and it is created in the created in the same directory as the script. So obviously it doesn't work after I install the package since its not accessible from there. 
I am looking for a way to create the database from the script at the time the package is being installed. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question asks how to install a database at the same time you are installing - which it looks like you're already able to do. _Where_ do you want the db to reside after installation is complete?

Comment: I want it in the same directory where the main script is installed so that its accessible to it. I want to create the database at the time of installing.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your main script?

```
import time

time.sleep(5)

execfile("./create_db.py")
```